# How to handle multiple clients on a socket server made with winsock on VB6?

Tags: vb6, winsock

i have this very simple chat app made in VB6 using winsock, but as you can see it only accept only one connexion, how can i handle multiple users? Thanks!

```
Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
    ' Finaliza la conexión
    Winsock1.Close

    txtLog = txtLog & "*** Desconectado" & vbCrLf

End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)

    If Winsock1.State <> sckClosed Then
        Winsock1.Close ' close
    End If

    Winsock1.Accept requestID

    txtLog = "Cliente conectado. IP : " & _
              Winsock1.RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf

End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Dim dat As String

    Winsock1.GetData dat, vbString
    txtLog = txtLog & "Cliente : " & dat & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to have an array of Winsock objects, and create a new one at runtime.  The new object you have created accepts the connection request.

So, in your connection request sub, you would have a new socket:

```
Dim ConnectionCount as long

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
    ConnectionCount=ConnectionCount+1

    Load Winsocks(ConnectionCount)
    Winsocks(ConnectionCount).Accept(requestID)

     txtLog = "Cliente conectado. IP : " & _
          Winsocks(ConnectionCount).RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Here is a tutorial that may help you better than my code:  http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5488

It follows the same idea.

Comment: Thanks @Brad but how can i create an array of winsocks??

Comment: Create a Winsock control on your form, and set its index to 0.  This makes it part of a control array.